# Параметр url в социальной кнопке

Tags: javascript

Передаю параметр url в социальную сеть при нажатии кнопки "поделиться" следующим образом:

```
http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=<ссылка>&description...
```

Но есть ситуации, когда при нескольких записях на одной странице требуется передать адрес с якорем (`<ссылка>#<якорь>`). Видимо, проблема в этом, так как при попытке передать таким образом ссылку остальные параметры теряются (при передаче обычной ссылки все в порядке). Предусмотрена ли, вообще, возможность передачи таких ссылок?

Comment: отчего не используете [виджет](https://vk.com/dev/share_details)?

Answer (score 1):

http://javascript.ru/window-location

Свойства объекта Location
Пример страницы, загруженной в браузере - *google.com:80/search?q=javascript#test*

**location.hash** - часть URL, которая идет после символа решетки '#', включая символ '#'   *#test*
**location.href** - весь URL - *google.com:80/search?q=javascript#test*

Comment: то есть, нет никакой возможности передать в социальную сеть параметр с символом решетки? А как же, если он встречается в тексте параметра `description`, например?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел в функции `encodeURIComponent()`, кодирующей специальные символы, переданные в GET-параметре.